# Custom folder structure for Swift Package

Tags: swift

When you generate a new Swift project with `swift init`, you get a `Sources` folder similar to [this](https://github.com/JohnSundell/Files). Wondering if there is a way to change the folder structure so it is like this:

```
main.swift
lib
lib/something.swift
```

And just get rid of the Sources directory.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you can use any folder structure that you want. The only thing in that references specific folders in that particular link you provided was the `path` in the Package.swift file. Which if you want to use, you can just update the path.

The project file keeps track of what swift files have been added into the project and which should be compiled and included in the resulting binary. As long as the files have been added via xcode you should be fine.

Comment: Wondering what to do if you add them outside of xcode.

Comment: You can add Swift source files from outside of xcode, but to include them in the project you need to select a folder/group within your project and "Add files to {project name}" so that xcode knows about them, this will add them to the project file and in the build phases > compile sources list